# Storing Data in Access from a report

Tags: ms-access

User runs a monthly report in MS Access, and wants to store the output in MS Access for Historical data reporting: what is the best way to do this?

I do not want the user to have to export to excel and then link that table to access, if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Important to consider:

All possible solutions which will use tables to store the history of reports can have a possible problem in future, when the resulting layout of the report changes.
Then the required fields maybe will change too and the history table and the UI which displays it will have to be adopted.

#### Solution with 'exporting' Reports:

There are two situatons to be distinguished:

- If all the calculated fields on the report do not belong to further tables or queries, but only base on the data stored in the history table, then you could create a query which will append the same data which the report is based on into a history table.
- If the calculated fields of the report base on additional tables or queries too, then you will have to build an explicitely query whose result contains all that calculated data to be able to store it in the history table too.

#### Solution with PDF files:

You should consider to store the history in PDF, by exporting the reports to well named files:

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Reportname", acFormatPDF, "x:\ReportHistory\2019-01-16-08-43-Reportname.pdf"`

You also could consider to store the username into the filename too.

Comment: Okay thank you, I think like you suggested I will right another query to store all data from Report into a table. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep the Access Database on the network or version control system and allow them to query it.  You could create queries or forms to view the queries within Access itself.

Comment: they can already query the data, there is a report that is produced by querying, they want the report stored back into a table, to keep historical data. if that makes sense. There is couple of fields that are calculated on the report

Comment: You could create a table with those calculated fields.